# JSON date coming out as a string of numbers from sql developer

Tags: javascript, json, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 var source =
  {
     contentType : 'application/json',
     datatype: "json",
     datafields: [{ name: 'id' },
                  { name: 'roleId' },
                  { name: 'roleDesc' },
                  { name: 'rate' },
                  { name: 'createdBy' },
                  { name: 'createdDate' },
                  { name: 'modifiedDate' }
                  ],
     id: 'id',
     type: "POST",
     url: ACTION.GET_ROLE_DETAILS,
     root: 'result',
     updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) {
        //synchronize with the server - send update command
        var data = {};
        data.id = rowdata.id; 
        data.roleId=rowdata.roleId;
        data.roleDesc=rowdata.roleDesc;
        data.rate=rowdata.rate;
        data.createdBy=rowdata.createdBy;
        data.createdDate=rowdata.createdDate;

        var d = new Date();
        d = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() +1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();

        data.modifiedDate= rowdata.d;

        console.log(data);

$.ajax({
           contentType : 'application/json',
           type: "POST",
           dataType: 'json',
           url: ACTION.SAVE_ROLE_DETAILS,
           data: JSON.stringify(data),
           success: function (data, status, xhr) {
              // update command is executed.
              if (loginGPID == rowdata.uniqueUserId) {
                 $("#cSpanFirstName").text(rowdata.firstName);
                 $("#cSpanLastName").text(rowdata.lastName);
              }
              $.ApplicationGeneralComponent.Notification({
                 type: APPLICATION.NOTY_TYPE_SUCCESS,
                 text: $.i18nManager('notify.user.update')
              });
              commit(true);
           },
           error: function () {
              commit(false);
           }
        });
     }
  };
```

This is the code I use to get and store the data but I also want to store when it was modified. This is correctly recognized in sqlDeveloper as the current date. But when I go to retrieve it, all I get out is the number "144792181000".

I don't really understand why it is doing this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is this tagged Java? I see no Java involved here.

Comment: try to convert the string number to int so this is you timestamp !!

Comment: Should that be done in the updaterow function? When I check it with alert(data.modifiedDate); Its still a date